# How to Escape Unicode word to be used in URL

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I want to escape Unicode word to be used in URL to make HTTPRequest, for example want to convert "محمود" to "%D9%85%D8%AD%D9%85%D9%88%D8%AF" I noticed that each character has converted to two HEX
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Convert to UTF-8, then url-encode chars not in `[[:alnum:]]`.

\Url-encoding is where a character is converted into `%<HIGHNIBBLE><LOWNIBBLE>` form, where `HIGHNIBBLE = (ch >> 4) & 0x0F` and `LOWNIBBLE = (ch & 0x0F)`.

Look into RFC 1738 (S) 2.2 for more details.

Because it looks like you're using java, you'll have to work with `byte[]` instead of `String` or `char[]`.

Comment: But how to convert HIGHNIBBLE and LOWNIBBLE to be -for example- %D9%85, Can you please give me a sample

Comment: I knew the answer
Add this class http://berryopen.googlecode.com/svn-history/r8/trunk/openpop/MyURLEncoder.java
and use this method MyURLEncoder.encode(str, "utf-8");

Comment: @JustMe Foreach `char ch` in UTF8 string array: `"%" + Integer.toHexString(Character.getNumericValue(ch))`

Comment: @moshbear That's not going to work once you get a character with a numeric value greater than 255.   Since the example is arabic, that's going to be every character in the string.

Comment: @MichaelDonohue You didn't read the part where I stated that the string for which to apply hex-encoding is **UTF-8**.

Comment: Encoding is a way to map between characters and bytes.  A string does not have an encoding, but a byte array does. Your code is still using Character manipulation, so you are confusing these.

Comment: It maps between code points and characters. UTF-16 is still a form of encoding when surrogates are in place to represent U+10000-U+10FFFF, so String[] _is_ encoded. UTF-16 is an encoding. UTF-8 inside UTF-16 is the UTF-8 string produced by using a `byte[]` constructor to String.